# Variable does not live long enough using match

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to create a new `Context` object and then return it if it works. However, Rust says that `&context` does not live long enough.

How can I force `context` to live as long as `Bo` in this case? Is it not enough to use the lifetime parameter `b` in the definition of the return type?

```
impl<'b> Bo {
    pub fn new() -> Result<&'b Context, BoError> {
        match Context::new() {
            Ok(context) => {
                return Ok(&context);
            }
            Err(e) => Err(BoError {}),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *and then return it if it works* — you aren't returning the `Context`, you are trying to return a *reference to it*. Once the function exits, the `Context` is destroyed and any references to it are invalidated. You just attempted to add memory unsafety to your program and Rust prevented it. Return `Result<Context, BoError>` instead.

Comment: I know. But what is the way to make `context` live as long as `Bo`?

Comment: You cannot *make* anything live longer via lifetimes; [they are descriptive, not prescriptive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/lifetimes.html#lifetimes-1). Return `Result<Context, BoError>` instead. There's nothing inside `Context` that cares about `Bo`, so there's no reason that the `Context` should not outlive `Bo`. If `Context` had a reference to `Bo`, then the compiler would prevent it from outliving it.